# Notifications on Page beside E-Mail-Notifications

Tags: notification

Is there a way to get the User-Notifications that normaly get sent via E-Mail (new Comment, new Entries etc.) somehow ON PAGE beside via eMail?

My Goal is to provide the member with notifications similiar to the notifications on Facebook oder Google+ etc. where you get all the notifications on page instead only per E-Mail.
The larger scope would be to use this in a «Notification-Center/-Flyout», with the Web-Push-Notifications API and other APIs.

Has anyone already developed such a System or how could it be possible? I am quite sure I am not the only one with this goal.

**Update**
To prevent missunderstanding: I need a solution to get the notifications out of the email-only-format to the frontend.

Comment: I think this would involve a fairly complex custom add-on. You'd need a module with it's own table to store the notifications (that's the easy part). Then you'd need an extension to hook into each event and add the notification to the queue. Definitely doable, but quite a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it with the [Pusher API](http://pusher.com/). For any event, store within the database and publish it. If that notification has been read update the status for the same. I think, you can get more detail by seeing the Pusher API doc. I hope, it would help you.

Comment: I don't know if Pusher API is the right thing for that. Meaning: I need a solution to get the notifications out of the email-only-format of now and get it to the frontend. Everything else (ajax or local/push-notifications, presentation etc.) I already know how to achive.

Comment: Yes, as you can see in my answer I mentioned for storing all those notifications into database and read status for any member (so that if any notification is read by member it wouldn't display). The approach of storing notifications into database is for non-realtime notifications. For realtime notifications Pusher API would work perfectly.